# Create stack using php task scheduler

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I used the AWS CLI to create a CloudFormation stack. Is there any way to create a stack using PHP task scheduler?

I have an online tools learning web site hosted in AWS that makes use of AWS services. I used this AWS CLI command:

```
aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name $Event_name-$emp_Id --template-body https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com
```

to create a stack in Amazon CloudFormation.

Can anyone help me in creating a CloudFormaion stack, without the help of the AWS CLI command and using PHP for scheduling the task?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [AWS SDK for PHP 3.x](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/getting-started/) to call the [createStack() command](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-cloudformation-2010-05-15.html#createstack):

```
$result = $client->createStack([
    'Capabilities' => ['<string>', ...],
    'ClientRequestToken' => '<string>',
    'DisableRollback' => true || false,
    'NotificationARNs' => ['<string>', ...],
    'OnFailure' => 'DO_NOTHING|ROLLBACK|DELETE',
    'Parameters' => [
        [
            'ParameterKey' => '<string>',
            'ParameterValue' => '<string>',
            'UsePreviousValue' => true || false,
        ],
        // ...
    ],
    'ResourceTypes' => ['<string>', ...],
    'RoleARN' => '<string>',
    'StackName' => '<string>', // REQUIRED
    'StackPolicyBody' => '<string>',
    'StackPolicyURL' => '<string>',
    'Tags' => [
        [
            'Key' => '<string>',
            'Value' => '<string>',
        ],
        // ...
    ],
    'TemplateBody' => '<string>',
    'TemplateURL' => '<string>',
    'TimeoutInMinutes' => <integer>,
]);
```